# Как авторизировать пользователя через standalone-приложение с помощью PHP и JS?

Tags: vkontakte-api

У меня проблема: есть сервис, написанный на php, для работы которому требуется standalone-приложение ВК. Чтобы ВК считал приложение standalone, нужно чтобы после авторизации пользователь переадресовывался на https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html. Всё бы ничего, но так я не могу получить access token чтобы продолжить работу. Ладно, предположим, что можно копировать адрес из адресной строки и потом уже обрезать скриптом, но это долго, сложно и не вызывает доверия.

Неужто нет никаких способов получить токен и, при этом, иметь права доступа для standalone-приложений?

Comment: Пробовали делать авторизацию через java, а все остальное пускать уже через php?

Comment: Аддон в браузер можно собрать и вопрос решится

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую документацию:

> Процесс авторизации приложения состоит из 3-х шагов:
>
> - Открытие окна браузера для аутентификации пользователя на сайте ВКонтакте.
> - Разрешение пользователем доступа к своим данным.
> - Передача в приложение ключа access_token для доступа к API.
>
> В качестве клиента может выступать любое приложение, имеющее доступ к
>   управлению Web-браузером.

То есть, вы должны показать пользователю страницу подтверждения доступа в браузере, который вы контролируете (можете узнать, куда произошло перенаправление). **Например, в `Android` для этих целей годится `WebView`**. После того, как доступ подтвержден, клиент будет перенаправлен на `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html?access_token=...`, откуда вы и вытащите ***access token***

А вообще, впредь, пожалуйста, читайте документацию и не просите других все разжевывать. Документация очень понятная и даже на русском. Удачи.

Comment: Но в описании написано, что "redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html Это обязательное условие для работы с методами, в описании которых указано, что они доступны только для Standalone-приложений."

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? @deff

Comment: Удалять комментарии со стены

Comment: @DeFF посмотрите обновление

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но у меня веб-приложение на PHP на бэкэнде и JS на фронтенде, и с помощью них авторизировать пользователя, сохранив доступ ко всем методам, не так уж и просто, и именно поэтому я задал вопрос.

Comment: Вам нужен эмулятор браузера. А сделать это на php сложно именно потому, что для этого этот метод не предназначен. @deff

Answer (score 0):

Важно понимать что при использовании своего `redirect_uri` вы получите не все права, например `wall` вы не получите, однако вы можете наряду с остальными `scope` использовать `offline` с редиректом в вк и тогда этот `access_token` будет вечным с нужными правами.

Comment: Вот, мне как раз нужно полноценно использовать wall и я даже не знаю, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Я же описал выше. Получите токен через вк и дальше используйте его сколько угодно.