# Как получить ссылку куда произошел redirect

Tags: php

Как сделать переход по ссылке1 внутри php и получить куда произошел редирект после перехода по ссылке1

Comment: В PHP вы обычно не **следуете** редиректам, а **выдаёте** их. Опишите ситуацию подробнее.

Comment: Например клиентская авторизация ВК, после успешной авторизации происходит переход на https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html при этом ключ доступа к API access_token и другие параметры передаются в URL-фрагменте ссылки, вот мне и надо достатать фрагмент access_token и сохранить его в БД

Comment: Чтобы это сделать, вам нужен контроль над HTTP-клиентом, через который пользователь подтверждает авторизацию в ВК. И если этим клиентом является браузер пользователя, из PHP у вас к нему доступа не будет.

Comment: @WinSide так сделать нельзя

Comment: Так каким клиентом вы авторизуетесь-то из PHP?

Comment: @WinSide  `oauth.vk.com/blank.html` - это для standalone приложений....... на `php` у вас уже **НЕ** standalone.... это СЕРВЕРНАЯ авторизация........на `js` существует `openAPI` но для него никакие редиректы на `blank.html` не происходит..... это для всяких андройд приложений и прчих

Comment: Похоже, что [**у нас это уже спрашивалось**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516171/181100).